# Replaced by animals, but also in webpages

Tags: riddle, word

I'm really very old,
Nowadays rarely used,
Replaced by animals
Of a feminine variety.

Give me more space,
And I'm in Asturian,
Or in some webpages
Of an HTML variety.

What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thou art

> DOTH

nowadays replaced by

> DOES.

With more space you might be

> DOT-H (ḥ, used in the Asturian language)

or

> "dot h" (.h, perhaps as a substring of ".html" -- I don't recall seeing "h" on its own used as an extension for HTML files).

Comment: Correct. To your comment in the last spoilertag: indeed I meant the thing appears *in* those webpages, not as a thing by itself.

Comment: I would say that there's a difference between appearing webpages and appearing in _names_ of webpages...

Comment: I got the first 3 right away but struggled to find it in a webpage. In retrospect it is right there as a substring in the href attributes in many pages. Very clever and tricky!